# Store data only after Stripe Payment method is verified in Flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

i am working on an app in which user h to book tickets, i integrated Stripe , and its working great. gut what is not working well is that i want to store tickets details in backend, so i code like this:-

```
                await createPayment('100', 'INR').then((value) {
                  _paymentIntentData = value != false ? value : null;
                });
                await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
                    paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
                        paymentIntentClientSecret:
                            _paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
                        googlePay: true,
                        style: ThemeMode.dark,
                        merchantCountryCode: 'INR',
                        merchantDisplayName: 'umar'));

                await displayPaymentSheet();

                await CloudServices().bookTicket(
                    widget.uid,
                    _chairStatus,
                    widget.snapshot
                            .data![widget.snapshot.data!.indexOf(widget.e)]
                        as route.Route);
```

Now the problem is that, if i click on close in payment sheet, the ticket details stores in backend, but it supposed to be stored only if payment is verified, theres no any method supported by Stripe like onPaymentVerified, so how can i achieve this.

Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

The presentPaymentSheet() [throws](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/packages/stripe/lib/src/stripe.dart#L326) Exception if the payment is failed or canceled. so you can just do a try and catch around it and only update your backend if the payment is succeeded.

Here's some example [code](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_sheet_screen.dart#L119).